# Format Currency into millions of dollars SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Can anyone help me format my dollars data into millions of dollars for SQL Server?

```
3,000,000

--> $3M
```

I have this but it's not working

```
SELECT     '$' + SUM(Sales_Information.Sales_in_Dollars / 1000000) 
                      AS [Sales in Millions]
```

Doing this gives me #Error

```
format(SUM(Sales_Information.Sales_in_Dollars / 1000000)
```

Comment: turn 3 million dollars into 3 dollars? Sounds like a job for your friendly neighborhood megabank.

Comment: @MarcB heh--see edits. the units is in millions

Comment: what's Sales_in_Dollars DataType? How many decimal points

Comment: @CodeSlinger How to check?

Comment: in management studio you can expand the database > then right click on table and choose Design. How many decimal points do you want the output. provide another example of the data.

Comment: or Run this against the table. SELECT column_name as 'Column Name', data_type as 'Data Type' FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_name = 'TABLE NAME'

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The `FORMAT` function has a way of trimming the thousands

each comma reduces the displayed value by 1000

e.g.

```
select format(3000000,'$0,,,.000B')
select format(3000000,'$0,,M')
select format(3000000,'$0,K')
```

(note that I had to use decimals to show 3 million in Billions)

Output:

> $0.003B
>   $3M
>   $3000K

Comment: can it be something dynamic, that based on value sql query returns 3B or 3M rather then having something static

Comment: only by using a `CASE WHEN` statement to split the field into cutoff points,

Answer (score 1):

Try this....

```
SELECT '$' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(100),CAST(3000000 AS MONEY),1)

RESULT:  $3,000,000.00
```

Comment: I'm looking for the result to be $3M

Answer (score 1):

Just make some edit as per your requirement:

```
CONCAT('$', ROUND(SUM(Sales_Information.Sales_in_Dollars) / 1000000), ' million)
```

Answer (score 1):

The one worked for me is:
CONCAT('$', ROUND(SUM(Sales_Information.Sales_in_Dollars)/ 1000000), 'M')

Answer (score 0):

just divide your currency with 1000000 and add an 'M' to its end